# Pandas grouping with filtering on other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe in Pandas:

| name | value | in | out |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 50 | 1 | 0 |
| A | -20 | 0 | 1 |
| B | 150 | 1 | 0 |
| C | 10 | 1 | 0 |
| D | 500 | 1 | 0 |
| D | -250 | 0 | 1 |
| E | 800 | 1 | 0 |

There are maximally only 2 observations for each `name`: one for `in` and one for `out`.
If there is only `in` for a `name` there is only one observation for it.

You can create this dataset with this code:

```
data = {
        'name': ['A','A','B','C','D','D','E'],
        'values': [50,-20,150,10,500,-250,800],
        'in': [1,0,1,1,1,0,1],
        'out': [0,1,0,0,0,1,0]
       }

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

I want to sum the `value` column for each `name` but only if `name` has both `in` and `out` record. In other words, only when one unique `name` has exactly 2 rows.

The result should look like this:

| name | value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 30 |
| D | 250 |

If I run the following code I got all the results without filtering based on `in` and `out`.

`df.groupby('name').sum()`

| name | value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 30 |
| B | 150 |
| C | 10 |
| D | 250 |
| E | 800 |

How to add the beforementioned filtering based on columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try something with `groupby`, `agg`, and `query` (like below):

```
df.groupby('name').agg({'name':'count', 'values': 'sum'}).query('name>1')[['values']]
```

Output:

```
        values
name        
A         30
D         250
```

You could also make `.query('name==2')` in above if you like but assuming it can occur max at 2 `.query('name>1')` would also return same.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you could filter before aggregation:

```
# check that we have exactly 1 in and 1 out per group
mask = df.groupby('name')[['in', 'out']].transform('sum').eq([1,1]).all(1)
# slice the correct groups and aggregate
out = df[mask].groupby('name', as_index=False)['values'].sum()
```

Or, you could filter afterwards (maybe less efficient if you have a lot of groups that would be filtered out):

```
(df.groupby('name', as_index=False).sum()
   .loc[lambda d: d['in'].eq(1) & d['out'].eq(1), ['name', 'values']]
)
```

output:

```
  name  values
0    A      30
1    D     250
```